# Linux cp copying files but not their contents

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, debian, cp

I am having some difficulty copying files from one mount point to another with the cp command inside a bash script.  For the sake of completeness, I execute the following at the very end of my script to force copy two log files:

```
cp -f /home/test1.log /media/usb0/
cp -f /home/test2.log /media/usb0/
```

The problem that I am having is that when I copy the two text files, the files are created in the new location but the copies are blank files.  Checking the original files shows they are not blank and they contain all the information that they are supposed to.  The strange thing is that if I copy other files from the destination to the source, the copy operation works perfectly, in other words, the following works everytime.

```
cp -f /media/usb0/test3.log /home/
```

I check the exit code of the cp command after each copy and in all instances cp exits with code 0, indicating a successful copy.  I thought that the issue might be permissions related so made sure the umask of the drive mounted to /media/usb0 is set to 0000 when it is mounted and I changed the destination directory's permissions to 777 temporarily to see if it would work then but this had the same result.

Can anyone provide an idea as to why this is happening?  I am completely at a loss as to why this is failing, especially since the original file and the copy differ after a supposedly successful copy.  Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Wild, wild guess: Do you remove the usb stick without unmounting later? Does the behavior change if you unmount properly (or at least call `sync`) at the end of the script?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I haven't tried calling sync at the end of the script since I unmount the drive before removing it.  However I will try adding sync to the script once I am back in the office Monday and see if that makes a difference.  Thanks again!

Comment: Is there anything suspicious in the `dmesg` output?

Comment: Not that I remember seeing, however I will check again on Monday morning.  I will update the post with what I find. Thanks!

Comment: It's fixed!  Good call Wintermute, adding `sync` after the copy operations did the trick.  It works 100% of the time now, thanks again!

Comment: @delta-v: This confused me. Doesn't `umount` do the `sync` job automatically?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, I didn't see this comment until today.  Yes, I would have thought that running `umount` would complete the `sync` automatically but for some reason it doesn't on my device.  If it helps, I am using an ancient version of bash, version `2.05b.0(1)-release`.